# Python - VTK boxwidget rotation-handlers

Tags: python, qt, opengl, pyqt, vtk

what I have seen so far, is that there is a widget which shows a 3D-bounding-box with 6-handles.
[Python Boxwidget Exampler](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Widgets/BoxWidget)

I would like translate the box by clicking [cntrl]+draging the handle and rotate only around the y-axis by clicking [shift]+draging the handle...

Every interaction should just only occur to the box in the scene and nothing else.

Do I have to overwrite the box-widget functions?
Or which exact function should I modify. Should I add an interaction obeserver?

And somehow - the handles are getting larger in size with the first 2 or 3 interactions, did someone experience the same issue?

**EDIT:**

[image]

That is my current code:

```
                self.boxWidget = vtk.vtkBoxWidget()
                self.boxWidget.SetInteractor(self.renderWindowInteractor)
                self.boxWidget.SetProp3D(self.boxes_3d_actors[obj_cls_name][0])
                self.boxWidget.SetPlaceFactor(1.0)
                self.boxWidget.PlaceWidget()
```

Where self.boxes_3d_actors is an array of vtk.vtkAssembly(), which consist of polylines.

Now I need somehow to overwrite the interaction event of the handles. The best would be to create an inherited class of vtkBoxwidget with own interaction functions.

Comment: What have you tried? Remember that SO is not a SW write service

Comment: Thank you for you hint and comment. I have been lately working on pointcloud visualizer and annotation tool. The issue is I don't know where to start to modify the handler operations. Else I would have shown you some code.

See edit.

Comment: I think that after 4 days you have already advanced something even if it does not work so you should show it to attract attention. I think you do not do it then your question will be closed, for now it is only avoided by the bounty does not allow voting to close your question.

Comment: I don't need a complete software - I just need a hint which exact part of the vtkboxwidget must be modified and maybe also how. I am full-time jobber and I am studying beside my job. So to set your assumptions into the right context..

Comment: 1) I have not said that you want a full SW, 2) Your personal things are irrelevant in SO since we only focus on the Q&A, 3) They are only recommendations. Goodbye, I will continue my way.

Comment: No problem - anyway - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Interactor according to your requirement. for common pan and rotate below is the code.

```
#Setting Renderer
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(self.boxes_3d_actors[obj_cls_name][0])
renwin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renwin.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Setting interactor
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(renwin)

boxWidget = vtk.vtkBoxWidget()
boxWidget.SetInteractor(interactor)
boxWidget.SetProp3D(self.boxes_3d_actors[obj_cls_name][0])
boxWidget.SetPlaceFactor(1.0)
boxWidget.PlaceWidget()
```

For setting the rotation and translate of object you can see the following links of documnetations:
https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Interaction/MouseEvents
https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCamera.html

Comment: I will give you the bounty and check to night how to solve it, and if your suggestion will be a help : ) thnx